# How to make a container / wrapper View Clickable in React

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

What is the equivalent for `linearLayout.setClickable(true);` **(Android)** in **React Native** below :

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }} ><Text>Hello World!<Text /><View />
```

I would like to make the `<View />` container / wrapper clickable.

Thank you all.

Comment: [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#clickable)

Comment: what about [TouchableNativeFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your container in a [Touchable](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches#touchables).

**For example:**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('onPress')}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }} >
    <Text>Hello World! </Text>
  </View>  
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Btw. In your example the closing tags were wrong, I corrected them in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap **View** in **TouchableOpacity**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handler}> 
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }} >
      <Text>Hello World!<Text />
   <View />  
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler()}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }} ><Text>Hello World!<Text /><View /> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

wrap those inside TouchableOpacity or any other Touch wrappers